# Translating Screen Coordinates [ x, y ] to Camera Pan and Tilt angles

Tags: trigonometry

I have a IP Camera which can Pan Tilt and Zoom. I am currently streaming live feed into the browser and want to allow user to click a point on the screen and the camera will pan and tilt so that the user clicked position will now become the center point of view.

Camera Pans from 0 to 360;
Camera tilts from -55 to 90;

My goal is when the video is being streamed to a screen of a pixel width 1920 by 1080 and let say user click on a point( x, y ) on the screen where 0,0 is the center of the screen i should be able to calulate the the Pan degree and and tilt degree i need to move the camera so that the camera is now looking where the user has clicked as the center point.

Camera has a Horizontal Fov of 65 degree; Aspect ratio of the camera is 16:9

Comment: Perhaps the people over at https://video.stackexchange.com/ would be of more help?

Comment: I thought this would be a more math related problem than a Camera / video related problem